# Is it possible to use the same java application with out any changes as a charm?

Tags: juju

I have a general question:

1. I have a application ( for example generate some output file from some input data)
2. is it possible to use same java application with out any changes as a charm, by other words I mean is it possible to put that app (java console app) on charm template?
3. or I need to change or rewrite my application to work in charm and juju architecture?
4. Does the node.js is my solution?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. Anything that will run on Ubuntu can be charmed.  Without knowing more about your application, you could expose the input data as a configuration parameter on the charm in `config.yaml` file within the charm. After the application is installed and the configuration parameter (input data) is set (`juju set charmname input-data="cat input_file"`) , the application could be triggered to compute the output.
2. Most of the time it is possible to charm up an application without changing the application.  The install hook would need to install a JRE (`apt-get install default-jre`) in this example and the config-changed hook could trigger/call the application when the input has been set (for example: `java org.rastin.Application input_data_file`)
3. I do not know the details of your application, so hard to answer this question.  Often no rewrite is needed, you just need to write the hook logic to install and configure the application in the charm.

Hope that helps!